# Windows Azure SQL Database Collation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How can I change the collation of my Azure SQL Database? I need to change it to Latin1_General_CI_AS

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

SQL Azure v12 supports altering the data collation of the database.However the catalog collation is fixed and cannot be altered

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the collation of a SQL Azure Database at the server level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#sscs

You can change it when creating the database initially.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I went about changing the default collation.

1) Create New Database Instance from the Portal with the proper Collation

2) Export Schema from Source and Apply To Destination

3) Disable all constraints

4) Using SSMS Import Wizard, copy all data from the old instance to the new instance.  This was extremely fast for me, as both instances were on the same server.

5) Re-enable all constraints

All columns picked up the new default Collation.  I went from CI to CS.

You can then rename the databases or just reference the new instance.

To check your columns, you can run this cmd before and after.

```
SELECT c.name, c.collation_name FROM SYS.COLUMNS c JOIN SYS.TABLES t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
```

Note: The import wizard doesn't copy everything; e.g., Users.
and this might not work for you if you specified a column level collation.